# Query to get all data from associated model on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have one `User` model and `StudentProfile` model associations are

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :student_profile 
end

class StudentProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
end
```

I want to render all fields of both table. SQL command for the action is

```
select * from users join student_profiles on student_profiles.user_id = users.id
```

But

```
User.joins(:student_profile)
```

shows only the fields of `User` table. I need to all info from both table in json fomat as I'll use this url for an ajax call.

Is there any way to realise this sql in active record query?

```
select * from users join student_profiles on student_profiles.user_id = users.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [select](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select) 
to select the fields that you want:

```rb
User.joins(:student_profile).select('users.*, student_profiles.*')
```

`*` is for selecting all fields

**Or** Choosing specific fields from `student_profiles` table:

```rb
User
  .joins(:student_profile)
  .select('users.*, student_profiles.first_name, student_profiles.last_name')
```

But I would suggest reading about active model serializers since you dealing with JSON.

Comment: First one was enough for me. I needed that one.-thanks